# Every time I run this python script, I get the output 'None', How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

When I ran this code I was expecting the output to be "Friend", instead I got "None". How do I fix This?

```
A = 'Friend'
b = 0
def Func(A, b):
    if b == 1:
        C = A
        return C
    else:
        b = b + 1
        A = A
        Func(A, b)
result = Func(A, b)
print(result)
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement does not return a value. Try `return Func(A,B)` instead of `Func(A,B)` on line 10.

Answer (score 0):

On line 10 you are simply calling Func(A, b) instead of returning a value. When nothing is returned from a function in python, python simply returns `None`. By adding a return statement it should return 'Friend'

```
A = 'Friend'
b = 0
def Func(A, b):
    if b == 1:
        C = A
        return C
    else:
        b = b + 1
        A = A
        return Func(A, b)
result = Func(A, b)
print(result) # >> Friend
```